# Web Audio API filter not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, html5-canvas, web-audio-api

I am in the process of developing an HTML5 canvas interactive piece that uses Createjs and the Web Audio API. I've managed to get audio working in Chrome/Firefox/Safari despite the deprecation of webkitAudioContext by Chrome and FF but not Safari. However, filters for some reason are not working in Safari, but sound still plays. Filters DO work in Chrome/FF.

I have my filters set up like this:

```
var sound = new Audio();
sound.src = './sounds/sound.mp3';
sound.autoplay = false;
sound.loop = true;
soundSource = context.createMediaElementSource(sound);
var soundFilter = context.createBiquadFilter();
soundFilter.type = "lowpass";
soundFilter.frequency.value = 500;
soundSource.connect(soundFilter);
soundFilter.connect(context.destination);
```

Am I unknowingly using a deprecated term or something? Live project can be found [here](http://playground.eca.ed.ac.uk/~s1463054/darksound_interactive/index.html). Cheers.

**UPDATE**: This has been recognised as a genuine bug by the WebKit team, and will be patched. [Full details here](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=143332)

Answer (score 4):

Apparently [Safari doesn't implement createMediaElementSource correctly](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=125031). So instead of redirecting the sound through your Web Audio nodes, it still just plays the sound directly to the audio device.

Is there any particular reason why you can't use a BufferSourceNode? It makes you jump through extra hoops to get the sound file and decode it, but it should work.

Comment: I think you mean "filter.LOWPASS", not "soundFilter.LOWPASS". I know that "filter.LOWPASS" is now deprecated, but unfortunately using "filter.LOWPASS" makes no difference for playback in Safari. The audio I'm using is wrapped in an <audio> tag, so I think what's happening is that when I'm calling for it, it's weirdly playing the file directly and ignoring the Web Audio API - no other browsers are doing this. I'll check out that monkeypatch though.

Comment: Yeah, unless I'm missing something, that monkeypatch is for outdated projects, not really a shim for browsers. Weirdly [I found a filter example](http://webaudioapi.com/samples/filter/) that works in Safari, but I've no idea why.

Comment: You're right, to use the monkeypatch in this situation you'd have to use the old constants and let the patch make it work on newer browsers. That's assuming "this situation" is what I thought it was, which apparently it's not.

Comment: I haven't found any solid info on exactly how up to date Safari's implementation is. My answer was pretty much speculation. Sounds like probably the filter isn't the issue; maybe createMediaElementSource doesn't work correctly on Safari. It would be weird, though, if it didn't work, but also didn't throw an exception.

Comment: Ah, that was it. Editing answer.

Comment: What was it? What you're saying about the monkeypatch is correct, but using deprecated constants and then a shim to get it working cross-browser surely can't be the best way. How familiar are you with Web Audio API? I think filters might work if audio saved in temp memory via createBuffer?

Comment: @Isaac, it was the createMediaElementSource bug, as described in my completely rewritten answer. You were essentially correct in your first comment when you said Safari was "playing the file directly and ignoring the Web Audio API". The monkeypatch is unnecessary.

Comment: Ah right, sorry just now seeing that. It looks like BufferSourceNode is the only option. Cheers.

Comment: See my above update; the WebKit team is now aware of this bug.